# Binomial sums from Bieberbach conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

It seems that I need some kind of hint or help with Exercise 33 from this wonderful blog [post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/05/02/246c-notes-3-univalent-functions-the-loewner-equation-and-the-bieberbach-conjecture/#initial) by T. Tao, namely with the following equality:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n - k} (-1)^j {2k + 2j \choose j} {n + j + k + 1 \choose n - k - j} = \frac{1 + (-1)^{n - k}}{2},
$$
for all $n \geq 1$ and $0 \leq k \leq n$. It must be some easy exercise since no hints provided, but I still have no ideas though I had already tried to use some induction or straightforward counting.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I spent some time on this and I got this so far: if you let $m=n-k$ and simplify the summation, it's not hard to see that for odd $m$, the $j$ and $m-j$ terms cancel each other out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain for integral $0\leq k\leq n$:
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n}\color{blue}{(-1)^j\binom{2j+2k}{j}\binom{n+k+j+1}{n-k-j}}\\
> &\ \,=\sum_{j=k}^n(-1)^{j+k}\binom{2j}{j-k}\binom{n+j+1}{n-j}\tag{1}\\
> &\ \,=\sum_{j=0}^\infty(-1)^{j+k}[z^j]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(\frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^k[u^{n-j}](1+u)^{n+j+1}\tag{2}\\
> &\ \,=(-1)^k[u^n](1+u)^{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(-u(1+u)\right)^j[z^j]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(\frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^k\tag{3}\\
> &\ \,=(-1)^k[u^n](1+u)^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4u(1+u)}}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdot\left(\frac{1+2u(1+u)-\sqrt{1+4u(1+u)}}{-2u(1+u)}\right)^k\tag{4}\\
> &\ \,=(-1)^k[u^n](1+u)^{n+1}\frac{1}{1+2u}\left(-\frac{u}{1+u}\right)^k\tag{5}\\
> &\ \,=[u^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-2u)^j(1+u)^{n-k+1}\tag{6}\\
> &\ \,=\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}(-2)^j[u^{n-k-j}](1+u)^{n-k+1}\tag{7}\\
> &\ \,=\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}(-2)^{n-k-j}[u^j](1+u)^{n-k+1}\tag{8}\\
> &\ \,=\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k+1}{j}(-2)^{n-k-j}\tag{9}\\
> &\ \,=-\frac{1}{2}\left((1-2)^{n-k+1}-1\right)\tag{10}\\
> &\ \,=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+(-1)^{n-k}\right)}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we shift the summation index to start with $j=k$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and set the index range from $0$ to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only. Here  we  use a cousin of the generating function  of the *[central binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* 
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{2m}{m}z^m&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\\
  \sum_{m=0}^\infty\binom{2m}{m-k}z^m&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\left(\frac{1-2z-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right)^k
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p}]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$.
- In (4) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z=-u(1+u)$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j u^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j [z^j]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we do some simplifications.
- In (6) we apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (7) we apply the rules as in (3) and we set the upper limit of the sum to $n-k$ since other values do not contribute.
- In (8) we change the order of summation $j\to n-k-j$.
- In (9) we select the coefficient of $u^j$.
- In (10) we apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a starter. We show the claim is valid for the special case $k=0$.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^j\binom{2j}{j}\binom{n+j+1}{n-j}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+(-1)^n\right)\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
\end{align*}
It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n}&\color{blue}{(-1)^j\binom{2j}{j}\binom{n+j+1}{n-j}}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n4^j\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{j}\binom{n+j+1}{n-j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty4^j[z^j](1+z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}[u^{n-j}](1+u)^{n+j+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=[u^n](1+u)^{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(4u(1+u)\right)^j[z^j](1+z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{3}\\
> &=[u^n](1+u)^{n+1}(1+4u(1+u))^{-\frac{1}{2}}\tag{4}\\
> &=[u^n](1+u)^{n+1}(1+2u)^{-1}\\
> &=[u^n]\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-2u)^j(1+u)^{n+1}\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n(-2)^j[u^{n-j}](1+u)^{n+1}\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n(-2)^{n-j}[u^j](1+u)^{n+1}\tag{7}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n+1}{j}(-2)^{n-j}\tag{8}\\
> &=-\frac{1}{2}\left((1-2)^{n+1}-1\right)\tag{9}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+(-1)^n\right)}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{j}=\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^j\binom{2j}{j}$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and set the upper limit of the series to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p}]z^qA(z)=[z^{p-q}]A(z)$.
- In (4) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z=4u(1+u)$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j u^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j [z^j]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (6) we apply the rules as in (3) and we set the upper limit of the sum to $n$ since other values do not contribute.
- In (7) we change the order of summation $j\to n-j$.
- In (8) we select the coefficient of $u^j$.
- In (9) we apply the binomial theorem.

Comment: Verified. (+1). A page with two different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from (here evidently $n\ge k$ for it to be meaningful).

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {2k+2j\choose j}
{n+k+j+1\choose n-k-j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {2n-2j\choose n-k-j}
{2n-j+1\choose j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {2n-2j\choose n-k-j}
{2n+1-j\choose 2n+1-2j}.$$

we write

$$(-1)^{n-k} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j 
{2n+1-j\choose 2n+1-2j} [z^{n-k-j}] (1+z)^{2n-2j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j 
{2n+1-j\choose 2n+1-2j} z^j  (1+z)^{-2j}$$

We get  no contribution to  the coefficient extractor when  $j\gt n-k$
and hence may continue with

$$(-1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n} \sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j 
{2n+1-j\choose 2n+1-2j} z^j  (1+z)^{-2j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n} \sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j 
z^j  (1+z)^{-2j} [w^{2n+1-2j}] (1+w)^{2n+1-j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n} [w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+1}
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j 
z^j  (1+z)^{-2j} w^{2j} (1+w)^{-j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n} [w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+1}
\frac{1}{1 + z w^2 / (1+z)^2 / (1+w)}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n+2} [w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+2}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^2(1+w) + z w^2}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n+2} [w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+2}
\frac{1}{(w+1+z)(wz+1+z)}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} [z^{n+1-k}] (1+z)^{2n+2} [w^{2n+1}] (1+w)^{2n+2}
\frac{1}{(w+1+z)(w+(1+z)/z)}.$$

Now the inner term is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^{2n+2}}
(1+w)^{2n+2}
\frac{1}{(w+1+z)(w+(1+z)/z)}.$$

Residues  sum to  zero  and  the residue  at  infinity  is zero  since
$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} 2\pi  R \times  R^{2n+2} / R^{2n+2}  /R^2 =
0.$ Hence we  may compute this from  minus the sum of  the residues at
$-(1+z)$ and $-(1+z)/z.$ The first one yields

$$-\frac{1}{(1+z)^{2n+2}} z^{2n+2} \frac{1}{-(1+z)+(1+z)/z}.$$

Replace this in the remaining coefficient extractor to get

$$(-1)^{n+1-k} [z^{n+1-k}] z^{2n+3} \frac{1}{1-z^2} = 0.$$

The second one yields

$$- \frac{z^{2n+2}}{(1+z)^{2n+2}} \frac{1}{z^{2n+2}}
\frac{1}{-(1+z)/z+1+z}$$

Once more replace this in the remaining coefficient extractor to get

$$(-1)^{n+1-k} [z^{n+1-k}] \frac{1}{-(1+z)/z+1+z}
= (-1)^{n+1-k} [z^{n+1-k}] \frac{z}{z^2-1}
\\ = - [z^{n+1-k}] \frac{z}{z^2-1}
= [z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{1-z^2}.$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
[[(n-k) \;\text{is even}]]
= \frac{1+(-1)^{n-k}}{2}}$$

as claimed.

Comment: Very nice and instructive contribution. (+1)

Comment: I've added an independent thread which might be interesting.

Comment: Interesting work.

Comment: Thanks, Marko. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Still seems not so simple as it looked to be.